# call server side methode and javascript code at the same time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I am developing the web application for Mobile where I want to open SMS editor from javascript.
below is my aspx code

```
<a class="redBtn fltrt" href="#" id="lnkBuy" runat="server" onclick="return makePayment()" onserverclick="lnkBuy_Click" rev='12' rel='21'>Buy</a>
```

and the onClick method

```
function makePayment()
    {
        try
        {
            var res=confirm('Are you sure to continue?');
            if(res == true)
            {
                window.location='sms:+334343434343';
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Error)
        {

        }
    }
```

here is I want to open the SMS editor and call to my code behind code

```
protected void lnkBuy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //code goes here
}
```

By using this and I am able to open the SMS editor but not be able to redirect to my code behind code.Can any body suggest me any way to do this both action in same time or any other convenient way.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the XMLHTTPRequest to send the call to my processing page and write another function to redirect to native SMS editor call.

Below is my code

```
function makeoldPayment(courseId,basketId)
    {
        try
        {
            var res=confirm('Are you sure to continue?');
            if(res == true)
            {                   
                var mobNo = document.getElementById('hidMNo').value;
                var lerid = document.getElementById('hidLId').value;
                var sendDataToServerReq = getXMLHttpRequest();

                var newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/Learners/SaveToDB.aspx?cid=1&mbid=123456&bid=43&lid=3;
                //alert(newURL)
                sendDataToServerReq.open("POST", newURL, false);

                sendDataToServerReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8;");
                gosms();
                sendDataToServerReq.send("mobno="+mobNo+"&lerid="+lerid+"&basketid="+basketId+"&recordid="+courseId);
                location.reload();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Error)
        {

        }
    }

    function gosms()
    {
    try
        {
        window.location='sms:+334343434343';
        }
        catch(Error)
        {
        }
    }



    function getXMLHttpRequest()
    {
       var httpRequest = null;

        // Create the appropriate HttpRequest object for the browser.
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest != null){
            httpRequest = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        }else if (window.ActiveXObject != null){
            // Must be IE, find the right ActiveXObject.
            var success = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < XMLHTTPREQUEST_MS_PROGIDS.length && !success; i++)
            {
                try{
                    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject(XMLHTTPREQUEST_MS_PROGIDS[i]);
                    success = true;
                }
                catch (ex)
                {}
            }
        }

        if (httpRequest == null){
            //alert("Error in HttpRequest():\n\nCannot create an XMLHttpRequest object.");
        }

        return httpRequest;
    }
```

hop this will help some one :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it the other way, doing the server call first, and then sending a redirect to the client to "sms:+334343434343" ?

Or alternatively, instead of using the ASP.NET callback mechanism, send an AJAX call to the server before the window.location change.

It depends on what you need to do server side.

Comment: thanks for reply but how to make this ajax call ?can you please help me out.

Comment: Yes, you could try doing the redirect in lnkBuy_Click.

Comment: For AJAX, you can use jQuery for instance which makes it easier. Check  out http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax for more information. Note that this approach won't call into lnkBuy_Click, but rather a page or a webservice on your server side.